# How to place two logos on the sides and nav in the middle?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website. I have 2 arbitrary logo's and a nav bar. I want to organise them into the order displayed in the image below, I've tried several methods; clear:both, float:left and display:inline-block.

Could someone shed some light on this issue for me in any way?

[image: Title bar for a website]

http://jsfiddle.net/genome314/862r132c/
Is what I'm currently working on.

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<img id="fLogo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
    <ul id="ontop">
        <li><a href="#Facebook">Facebook</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="underneath">
      <li><a href="#Home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Games">Games</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Trailers">Trailers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Walkthroughs">Walkthroughs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
<img id="sLogo" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/81/Wikimedia-logo.svg"></img>
```

CSS:

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;
overflow:auto;}
#fLogo{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
#sLogo{
width:100px;
height:100px;
}
#titleBar{
}
#nav ul{
list-style:none;
width:450px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background-color: #333;
overflow:hidden;
float:centre;}
#nav li {
float: left; }
#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 10px 14px;
font-weight: bold;
color: #E6E600;
border-right: 1px solid #FFFFCC; }
#nav li:first-child a {
border-left: 1px solid #FFFFCC; }
#nav li a:hover {
color: #FF3300;
background-color: #FFFF99; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add a wrapper element to the middle Facebook and main menu
- Add a `min-width` to the #nav to prevent the line break
- Set the 2 logos and middle menu all `float: left`

For more details look at the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rhk7xnm8/1/), I also cleaned up the code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You have `float: centre` on your nav bar. There is no such thing as float: center.

What you need to do is, if you're going to use floats, is to float all of your object left. So set the image, the UL and the other image to `float: left`

Comment: I have updated the link. This seems to work except the 2nd image (the one on the right) is not symmetrical with the image on the left. I.e. it dips